# javascript reduce find max in array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, mapreduce

I want to find the max number among the first and second elements of each array inside the array of arrays separately:

```js
function largestOfElements(mainArray) {
  return mainArray.map(function(subArray) {
    return subArray.reduce(function(previousLargestNumber, currentLargestNumber) {
      return (currentLargestNumber > previousLargestNumber) ? currentLargestNumber : previousLargestNumber;
    }, 0);
  });
}
console.log(largestOfElements([
  [],
  [13, 47],
  [38, 35],
  [24, 34]
]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

the current way returns an array of the largest numbers in each array.
How can I return the largest of the first elements and the largest of the second elements?
the expected result will be:

`[38, 47]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce`.

- The initial value for the function reduce are the min values to start getting the highest values.
- Check for the length of the current array.
- Use destructuring assignment to get the first and second value [first, second].
- Check the current value against first and second respectively to get the highest.

```js
var array = [
  [],
  [13, 47],
  [38, 35],
  [24, 34]
];

var result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (c.length) {
    var [first, second] = c;
    if (first > a.f) a.f = first;
    if (second > a.s) a.s = second;
  }
  
  return a;
}, {f: Number.MIN_VALUE, s: Number.MIN_VALUE}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: could you add more explanation please?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [
  [],
  [13, 47],
  [38, 35],
  [24, 34]
];

console.log([0,1].map(i => Math.max(...array.map(v => v[i]).filter(v => v))));
```